# IFERROR, INDEX, MATCH returning zeros instead of blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I am using the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Cleaned Post'!W:W,MATCH(Combined!$C2,'Cleaned Post'!$C:$C,0))," ")
```

This formula is working beautifully, except that for blank cells, it's returning "0". I would like blank cells to be return as blank.

Specifically, this is what I have

Sheet 1 (entitled Cleaned Post)

```
Name        Email      Age Gender   Task #1
Andrew 888@gmail.com   18    1        80
Jason  687@gmail.com   20    1        95
Judy   432@gmail.com   18    2        __
Jack   236@gmail.com   24    1        65
```

Sheet 2 (entitled Combined) - What I'm getting

```
    Email      Task#1
888@gmail.com   80
687@gmail.com   95
432@gmail.com    0
236@gmail.com   65
```

Sheet 2 (entitled Combined) - What I want

```
    Email     Task#1
888@gmail.com   80
687@gmail.com   95
432@gmail.com   __
236@gmail.com   65
```

What do I need to do to adjust this formula?

Comment: Unfortunately there is *nothing* you can do in Excel to get a blank cell, other than leaving it blank. You can get an empty string but it's not the same as a blank.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm guesssing an empty string is what the OP really wants. Use `""` instead of `0`.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. Sorry.

Comment: You could try going into File-->Options-->Advanced and make sure Show a zero in cells that have zero value is unchecked (untested).

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your suggestions. I unfortunately don't have an "Options" within the File drop down menu. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @LauraLigouri I don't at the moment. What is some sample input into the formula and what is the expected result?

Comment: @LauraLigouri - Try `Alt+F, T` for Excel 2010-13, the 'pizza-button' in the top left corner for Excel 2007 or for Excel 97-2003 use Tools, Options.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What sort of values is your formula returning? If they are text values it's sufficient to concatenate a "null string" to your `INDEX/MATCH` formula like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Cleaned Post'!W:W,MATCH(Combined!$C2,'Cleaned Post'!$C:$C,0))&"","")
```

That also works for numbers except it will convert them to text so if you don't want that you can try this version:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Cleaned Post'!W:W,MATCH(Combined!$C2,'Cleaned Post'!$C:$C,0))="","",INDEX('Cleaned Post'!W:W,MATCH(Combined!$C2,'Cleaned Post'!$C:$C,0))),"")
```

Comment: Barry, you are a lifesaver! I tried something very similar but was one input off. This did the trick. Thanks SO MUCH!

Comment: Year and a half later and this is _exactly_ what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but...
I settled for using conditional formatting..
if the returned value was 0, change the text color to match the background...